# How to extract top item from a defaultdict(list)?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, defaultdict

I am new to working with `defaultdict`s.
I have a matching script that's places a unique identifier as a "key" and then it puts a list of potential matches for the identifier into a dictionary using a `defaultdict(list)` . The matches are company names, addresses, and matching scores (based on matching algorithms). Sometimes it is a 1-1 match, meaning there is 1 key associated with a match, but sometimes the algorithms catches close matches so there are sometimes multiple matches. For those Id like to select this highest scored match.

**Goal:** *Extract data from defaultdict(list) for each unique identifier. If unique identifier has more than 1 value, then exact the data with the highest Lev Score, Fuzzy Score and Jaro score.*

**Here's a preview of the data:**

```
#imports
from collections import defaultdict
test_dic_stack = defaultdict(list)

#testing data (unique1 has a 1-1 match &  unique2 has a 1-5 match)
test_dic_stack['unique1'].append({'Account Name': 'company1', 'Matching Account': 'company1', 'Account_Address': '123 Road', 'Address_match': '123 Road',  'Lev_score': 98.0, 'Fuzzy_score': 100, 'Jaro_Score': 99.0})
test_dic_stack['unique2'].append({'Account Name': 'company1', 'Matching Account': 'company1', 'Account_Address': '1 awesome street', 'Address_match': '1 awesome street',  'Lev_score': 91.0, 'Fuzzy_score': 89, 'Jaro_Score': 99.0})
test_dic_stack['unique2'].append({'Account Name': 'company2', 'Matching Account': 'company2', 'Account_Address': '1 awesome street', 'Address_match': '1 awesome st',  'Lev_score': 71.0, 'Fuzzy_score': 82, 'Jaro_Score': 84.0})
test_dic_stack['unique2'].append({'Account Name': 'company3', 'Matching Account': 'company3', 'Account_Address': '1 awesome street', 'Address_match': '1 awesome street suite 1',  'Lev_score': 88.0, 'Fuzzy_score': 89, 'Jaro_Score': 90.0})
test_dic_stack['unique2'].append({'Account Name': 'company4', 'Matching Account': 'company4', 'Account_Address': '1 awesome street', 'Address_match': '1 awe street',  'Lev_score': 81.0, 'Fuzzy_score': 90, 'Jaro_Score': 86.0})
test_dic_stack['unique2'].append({'Account Name': 'company5', 'Matching Account': 'company5', 'Account_Address': '1 awesome street', 'Address_match': '1 awe st',  'Lev_score': 70.0, 'Fuzzy_score': 86, 'Jaro_Score': 89.0})

#defaultdict preview
defaultdict(list,
            {'unique1': [{'Account Name': 'company1',
               'Matching Account': 'company1',
               'Account_Address': '123 Road',
               'Address_match': '123 Road',
               'Lev_score': 98.0,
               'Fuzzy_score': 100,
               'Jaro_Score': 99.0}],
             'unique2': [{'Account Name': 'company1',
               'Matching Account': 'company1',
               'Account_Address': '1 awesome street',
               'Address_match': '1 awesome street',
               'Lev_score': 91.0,
               'Fuzzy_score': 89,
               'Jaro_Score': 99.0},
              {'Account Name': 'company2',
               'Matching Account': 'company2',
               'Account_Address': '1 awesome street',
               'Address_match': '1 awesome st',
               'Lev_score': 71.0,
               'Fuzzy_score': 82,
               'Jaro_Score': 84.0},
              {'Account Name': 'company3',
               'Matching Account': 'company3',
               'Account_Address': '1 awesome street',
               'Address_match': '1 awesome street suite 1',
               'Lev_score': 88.0,
               'Fuzzy_score': 89,
               'Jaro_Score': 90.0},
              {'Account Name': 'company4',
               'Matching Account': 'company4',
               'Account_Address': '1 awesome street',
               'Address_match': '1 awe street',
               'Lev_score': 81.0,
               'Fuzzy_score': 90,
               'Jaro_Score': 86.0},
              {'Account Name': 'company5',
               'Matching Account': 'company5',
               'Account_Address': '1 awesome street',
               'Address_match': '1 awe st',
               'Lev_score': 70.0,
               'Fuzzy_score': 86,
               'Jaro_Score': 89.0}]})
```

**Here's my requested result:**

Extract unique1 data and extract unique2 "best matched" data. **Note sometimes the best match isnt always first**

```
results = [{'unique1': {'Account Name': 'company1',
               'Matching Account': 'company1',
               'Account_Address': '123 Road',
               'Address_match': '123 Road',
               'Lev_score': 98.0,
               'Fuzzy_score': 100,
               'Jaro_Score': 99.0},

          'unique2': {'Account Name': 'company1',
               'Matching Account': 'company1',
               'Account_Address': '1 awesome street',
               'Address_match': '1 awesome street',
               'Lev_score': 91.0,
               'Fuzzy_score': 89,
               'Jaro_Score': 99.0}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dictionary comprehension with `max` using the sum of the three scores as key.

Assuming `d` the input dictionary.

```
out = {k:max(v, key=lambda x: sum((x['Fuzzy_score'], x['Lev_score'], x['Jaro_Score'])))
       for k,v in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'unique1': {'Account Name': 'company1',
  'Matching Account': 'company1',
  'Account_Address': '123 Road',
  'Address_match': '123 Road',
  'Lev_score': 98.0,
  'Fuzzy_score': 100,
  'Jaro_Score': 99.0},
 'unique2': {'Account Name': 'company1',
  'Matching Account': 'company1',
  'Account_Address': '1 awesome street',
  'Address_match': '1 awesome street',
  'Lev_score': 91.0,
  'Fuzzy_score': 89,
  'Jaro_Score': 99.0}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this but I'm getting an Type error saying 'int' object is not iterable.

Comment: ah I just had to put the Items in brackets! Cool this looks like they got them into a list. this worked! I am seeing the best scored item

Comment: question what about if one of the scores has either a "nan" value or a "n/a" value?

Comment: Well, it depends how you want to handle it. You could add the number of non NaN as a max key, or compute the mean score on non NaN, is up to you. Best might be to write a function that takes one dict in an returns one score. You have to decide the logic ;)

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. So these acccouts have sales and call activities associated with them. (I didnt add those as a dic key in this example) sometimes they have a value and sometimes they dont. I  was thinking about just summing the total values and then skipping the sales/calls if there were nullor 'N/A'. I think it would throw an error if I added the sales columns to the brackets and they contained nulls/NAs?  (x['Sales'],x['Calls'])